# Fedora 22 - Can't Access GNOME Lock Screen

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, gnome, screensaver

I recently installed Fedora 22 and I'm using GNOME v3.16.2. I am new to Fedora, but moderately experienced with Linux. I cannot figure out how to lock my screen with a keyboard shortcut.

I have tried setting the "Lock Screen" shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in the keyboard settings. But no matter what I set key binding to, nothing ever happens.

The only way I can lock my screen is to manually open `XScreenSaver`, start the daemon and manually lock the screen. But this is not the lock screen I am used to from running an older version of GNOME on SUSE 11.

**EDIT**

After a couple of days of no responses, I would like to change my question a bit.

- How can I check that the GNOME screensaver is actually runnable?
- Can it be launched from the command line? (How?)
- What is the name of the process so I can check to see if it is actually running?
- Can I reinstall the lock screen via DNF?

Comment: after doing a search on GNOME tag, I have discovered that almost all of the questions asked with this tag have gone unanswered. Perhaps there is a better place for these questions. I will comment for others as I find better sources / answers.

Comment: Seems to me that your question ended up being all over the place. Could you updated it to reflect one issue (or two)? Mainly because you are talking about 3 different ways to achieve (almost) the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set up keyboard shortcuts you need to go to **Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **System**. Then you'll find the **Lock screen**.
This works for me without any issue.

Also, I recommend installing the **Tweak Tool** as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a fresh install of Fedora Server 23.
Try running (as root):

```
dnf install system-switch-displaymanager
system-switch-displaymanager gdm
systemctl enable gdm
```

Log off/on or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd> to restart the display manager.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> should now lock your screen.

Comment: Did not work for me on Fedora 27/Gnome 3.26.2